# Auhtorization not trapping invalid username and fails at roles

Tags: c#, membership-provider

I am using the following for my authorisation and login routine but when I get a user who enters and invalid username its doest appear to be getting gaught also when the record set of the reader is empty Ie does not contain any roles it bombs out at the roles line.

```
int userId = 0;
string roles = string.Empty;
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolSql"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
                        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        lblerror.Text = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        lblerror.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        lblerror.Text = "Account has not been activated.";
                        lblerror.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUsername.Text.Trim(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), chkRemberMe.Checked, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                        {
                            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                        }
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), chkRemberMe.Checked));
                        lblerror.Visible = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

It is throwing an exception here at roles=reader. I have included my stored procedure below as well

```
--[Validate_User] 'admin', '12345'
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate_User]
    @Username NVARCHAR(20),
    @Password NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @UserId INT, @LastLoginDate DATETIME, @RoleId INT

    SELECT @UserId = UserId, @LastLoginDate = LastLoginDate, @RoleId = RoleId 
    FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username AND [Password] = @Password 

    IF @UserId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT UserId FROM UserActivation WHERE UserId = @UserId)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Users
            SET LastLoginDate =  GETDATE()
            WHERE UserId = @UserId 

            SELECT @UserId [UserId], 
                    (SELECT RoleName FROM Roles 
                     WHERE RoleId = @RoleId) [Roles] -- User Valid
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT -2 [UserId], ''  RoleName-- User not activated.
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 [UserId], '' RoleName -- User invalid.
    END
END
```

Comment: You are asking for the column `Roles` in your C# code, but return the column `RoleName` from your two else-statement SQL, that would be why you are getting the error

Comment: One note about your code: You are passing the @password parameter in plaintext to the stored procedure, which leaves it open to being sniffed/traced/grabbed from the database. Please seed and hash your passwords before sending them to the database, both when setting them and checking the login

Comment: @BerndLinde cant bieleve i did not see it and yes i no to encrypt this is just tesing module phase

Comment: @BerndLinde it actually is not its bringing back roles but in this way when i execute the proc in managment studio?? http://snag.gy/8kqxR.jpg

Comment: I just tried your code (modified a bit as to run without a table and RoleName > Roles) and the C# gets the column name from the reader when executed. Check that the right version of the stored proc is called on the right database if you are not getting results back. Otherwise use the SQL Profiler to check what is actually being called